# ScrollView causes scrolling when adding margin/padding even if the content don't need extra space

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, padding, margin

I'm working on this layout containg a scroll view which contains a linear vertical layout that wraps an image on top and a couple of text views. Even if no extra space is needed to show the content the scrolling happens anyway. Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ToolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ShowProfileActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_image_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/user_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/user"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_info_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/full_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/datebirth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:text="@string/birthdate"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gender"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:text="@string/gender"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_nickname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/nickname"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/nickname"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/email_address"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_state"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/state"
                    android:text="@string/state"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_city"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/city"
                    android:text="@string/city"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_postal_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/postal_code"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/postal_code"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/address"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The following is an image showing the problem. How is possible to prevent this?
I've already tried some attributes for the ScrollView like `fillViewport` to true but that doesn't help.

[image]